# Flaw in a Lottery Game and a Second Opportunity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayesian, lotteries

In my country there is a ***Lottery Game*** called ***"Melate"***. It works like this:

> Get a Melate flyer, pick up 6 Numbers from 1 to 56, it doesn't matter the order, each combination costs $15, then wait for the raffle where a tombola is going to draw 6 balls, these are going to be called ***"The Natural Numbers"*** and then it is going to draw another ball, this is going to be called ***"The Additional Number"***

[image]
[image]

> Check if you win any prize depending on the number of balls matched:
>
> - 1st Prize= 6 "Natural Numbers" (Variable Prize)
> - 2nd Prize= 5 "Natural Numbers" and the "Additional Number" (Variable Prize)
> - 3rd Prize= 5 "Natural Numbers" (Variable Prize)
> - 4th Prize= 4 "Natural Numbers" and the "Additional Number" (Variable Prize)
> - 5th Prize= 4 "Natural Numbers" (Variable Prize)
> - 6th Prize= 3 "Natural Numbers" and the "Additional Number" ( \$161.29 )
> - 7th Prize= 3 "Natural Numbers" ( \$43.01 )
> - 8th Prize= 2 "Natural Numbers" and the "Additional Number" ( \$32.25 )
> - 9th Prize= 2 "Natural Numbers" ( \$26.88 )

In order to compute the probabilities for every prize, the way I reasoned the problem was:

The total of possible combinations without repetition of 6 elements choosen between 56 is:

$ \binom{56}{6} = 32,468,436 $

The amount of possible combinations without repetition of x "Natural Numbers" is given by:

$ \binom{6}{x} $

The amount of possible combinations without repetition of "The Additional Number" is given by:

$ \binom{1}{1} $

The amount of possible combinations without repetition of the "y left spaces" that they can be chosen from any of the Remaning Numbers (56 - 6 -1 = 49) is given by:

$ \binom{49}{y}  $

These three events are dependent, so:

P(X and Y and A) = P(X)P(Y after X)P(A after X)

So, this is the way I tried to compute the probabilities:

**1st Prize**

$ P(1st Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{1}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.000000030799 = 0.0000030799 \% $

**2nd Prize**

$ P(2nd Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{5}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{6}{32,468,436} \frac{1}{32,468,436} = \frac{1}{5,411,406} ≈  0.00000018479 = 0.000018479 \% $

**3rd Prize**

$ P(3rd Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{5}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{1}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{6}{32,468,436} \frac{49}{32,468,436} = \frac{7}{773058} ≈ 0.000009055 = 0.0009055 \% $

**4th Prize**

$ P(4th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{1}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{15}{32468436} \frac{49}{32468436} = \frac{35}{1546116} ≈ 0.000022637 = 0.0022637 \% $

**5th Prize**

$ P(5th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{15}{32,468,436} \frac{1176}{32,468,436} = \frac{70}{128843} ≈ 0.00054329 = 0.054329 \% $

**6th Prize**

$ P(6th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{50}{6}} = \frac{20}{32,468,436} \frac{1176}{32,468,436} \frac{1}{32,468,436} = \frac{280}{386529} ≈ 0.000724396 = 0.0724396 \% $

**7th Prize**

$ P(7th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{20}{32,468,436} \frac{18424}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.011348 = 1.1348 \% $

**8th Prize**

$ P(8th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{50}{6}} = \frac{15}{32,468,436} \frac{18424}{32,468,436} \frac{1}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.0085116 = 0.85116 \%$

**9th Prize**

$ P(9th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{49}{4}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{15}{32,468,436} \frac{211,876}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.097884 = 9.7884 \% $

My first question is, the probabilities that I computed are correct? if they are, I think this lottery game has a flaw since P(7th Prize) > P(8th Prize) and 7th Prize > 8th Prize . In my opinion it should be 7th Prize < 8th Prize

I was watching a webpage where they computed the probabilities of the same lottery and they obtained simmilar results (altough they don't show the computing method):

> Prize and Probability
>
> - 1st Prize= 1:32.468.436
> - 2nd Prize= 1:5.411.406
> - 3rd Prize= 1:110.437
> - 4th Prize= 1:44.175
> - 5th Prize= 1:1.840
> - 6th Prize= 1:1.380
> - 7th Prize= 1:88
> - 8th Prize= 1:117
> - 9th Prize= 1:10

So, am I right? Is there a flaw in the 7th Prize?

If my probabilities are computed correctly, it is also possible to say:

$ P(nth Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{6- \big\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\big\rfloor} \binom{49}{\big\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\big\rfloor} }{\binom{56}{6}}   $

for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor-function

After that, you can have a second opportunty of playing by ***sticking with your previous combination used in Melate***, this second chance is called ***"Revancha"***, each combination costs $10

[image]

> The Prizes are:
>
> - 1st Prize= 6 "Natural Numbers" (Variable Prize)
> - 2nd Prize= 5 Natural Numbers (Variable Prize)
> - 3rd Prize= 4 Natural Numbers (Variable Prize)
> - 4th Prize= 3 Natural Numbers ( \$26.88 )
> - 5th Prize= 2 Natural Numbers ( \$10.75 )

Following the same logic, the probabilities that I computed are:

**1st Prize**

$ P(1st Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{1}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.000000030799 = 0.0000030799 \% $

**2nd Prize**

$ P(2nd Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{5}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{50}{1}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{6}{32,468,436} \frac{50}{32,468,436} = \frac{25}{2705703} ≈ 0.000009240 = 0.0009240 \% $

**3rd Prize**

$ P(3rd Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{50}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{15}{32,468,436} \frac{1225}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.000565934 = 0.0565934 \% $

**4th Prize**

$ P(4th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{50}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{20}{32,468,436} \frac{19600}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.012073 = 1.2073 \% $

**5th Prize**

$ P(5th Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{56}{6}} \frac{\binom{50}{4}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{15}{32,468,436} \frac{230,000}{32,468,436} = \frac{70}{128843} ≈ 0.10639 = 10.639 \% $

Does the probability of winning with the same combination changes? Is it better to buy a new combination and play ***"Melate"***, or should I stick with the old one and play ***"Revancha"***?

After that, there is also a third oppotunity, where you can continue sticking with the same combination again, this third opportunity is called ***"Revanchita"***, it costs $5 for each combination ..

[image]

> The Prizes are:
>
> - 1st Prize= 6 "Natural Numbers" (Variable Prize)

The probability that I computed is:

**1st Prize**

$ P(1st Prize)= \frac{\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{56}{6}} = \frac{1}{32,468,436} ≈ 0.000000030799 = 0.0000030799 \% $

should I stick with the old combination again?

This looks something similar to the ***"Monty Hall Problem"***, should I use the ***Bayes Theorem***? Do probabilities change, or stay the same? and why? I am inclined to believe the probabilities are the same, but it is a little bit weird that ***"Revancha"*** only offers 5 prizes and ***"Revanchita"*** only one prize insted of the original 9 prizes, as if it was easier to win any prize .. if you know that a previous combination didn't win anything in the past, does the probability that the same combination wins anything increases? I don't think so, but if I reverse the question, What are the odds that the same combination wins twice?, it seems more tempting to believe that the past affects the current raffle but I am new on Probability Theory, so I don't really know

Comment: It makes sense that getting exactly 1 specific number and 2 from 6 is going to be harder than getting 3 of 6 numbers. I would guess that getting the "additional number" and 3 from the pool of 6 is also less likely than the additional number and 4 natural numbers; or that they are pretty similar in odds.

Comment: But then, technically, the prizes should change, and assign a correct prize according to the probability of the event

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look until the end but the probabilities that you're computing for every prize are wrong.

I took only the 7th Prize case, in that one you have the following:
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{49}{3}}{\binom{56}{6}}$$

But you're dividing with $\binom{56}{6}$ twice, which is not needed in all the cases. If you recompute your probabilities correctly you're going to see that they differ from what they are specifying on the website.

Comment: I am not dividing twice, I am using Lowest common denominator, I just write them in that way to emphasize that every fraction corresponds to certain event. But even so, are you saying that the external website is also wrong?

Comment: What is the general formula that you use, then?, is not; $  P(nth Prize) = \frac{\binom{6}{6- \big\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\big\rfloor} \binom{49}{\big\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\big\rfloor} }{\binom{56}{6}}   $?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, in your examples the denominator shows up twice, which implies multiplication.

Comment: Oh yes, I tought I was adding fractions, I am so dumb .. But then, How did you get to that expresion? They are supposed to be dependent events, so they need to be multipled, not adding. Is this wrong: P(X and Y and A) = P(X)P(Y after X)P(A after X) ?

Comment: The fact that you're picking 3 cards out of 49 not of 55 makes sure they are dependent. Your formula is incorrect. I'd suggest looking up the axioms of probability before.

Comment: The Kolmogorov Axioms that lay Measure Theory as the Foundations of Probability? is it necessary? I don't know Measure Theory